# How do I install babel.messages module in Ubuntu?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install using

```
sudo apt-get install babel.messages
```

but getting error:

> ImportError: No module named babel.messages

Please let me know how to install in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This would be better asked on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) or [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com)

Answer (score 1):

Try that with using this command:

```
# pip install babel
```

It will work well

Comment: Please provide more details if possible. Kindly go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu versions older than 17.04, you can install python-babel from the Ubuntu repositories by running the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-babel
```

For Ubuntu versions from 17.04 and also on older versions you can install it via `pip`, the Python package manager as:

```
pip install babel
```

If you don't have `pip` installed yet, you can install it as:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```